# RBAC always return the exception

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks, rbac, yii2-basic-app

[this is the entry for auth_item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy5XU.png)i'm trying to use rbac in yii2-basic framework.

code is as follow:

config/web.php:

```
'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        ],
```

controller:

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
        if(Yii::$app->user->can('countries/create')){
            $chk = 'Can Do';
        }else{
            $chk = 'Can Not Do';
        }
    echo $chk;exit();
}
```

Comment: How did you initialize the rules? Are you sure there is an entry on authentication_items for 'countries/create'? It looks like you are trying to use controller/action as the permission name.

Comment: just check i have edited the post and added the ss for the entry for auth_item

Comment: You also need to assign that item to the users that are allowed that permission. Then, on the controller, you need to check if the user can "permission". The permission you are creating is called 'admin', but you are checking for 'countries/create'.

Comment: Did you check the [guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#using-console-command) section on using a console controller to create a RBAC structure? I could *answer* your question here, but it would be pretty much a copy of that post using your role names.

Comment: i would be vey thankful if you could do it. it's like m making some mistake.

Comment: and i did assign the item to the user.

Answer (score 0):

### Make sure to check that all the points below are working as expected.

> The information comes from [the Yii2 guide pages](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#using-console-command) and it is explained in more detail there.

1. Configure the application to use RBAC with the data stored on the database.

```php
'authManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
],
```

2. Add and assign roles and permissions to the database.

*One way*, probably the simplest, is to use a console controller, but then you have to deal with permissions on user creation and update somewhere else in your code.

```php
<?php
namespace app\commands;

use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class RbacController extends Controller
{
    public function actionInit()
    {
        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
        $auth->removeAll();
        
        // add "create country" permission better remove '/'
        $createCountry = $auth->createPermission('createCountry');
        $createCountry->description = 'Create a new country';
        $auth->add($createCountry);

        // add "admin" role and give this role the "createCountry" permission
        $adminRole = $auth->createRole('admin');
        $auth->add($adminRole);
        $auth->addChild($adminRole, $createCountry);

        // Assign roles to user by id, make sure this is the user that you 
        // are using when testing
        $auth->assign($adminRole, 1);
    }
}
```

3. Add some logs in your controller to check what is not working as expected.

```php
public function actionCreate()
{
    // Logs just to find what is wrong, remove them later
    if (($user = Yii::$app->user->identity) === null) {
        Yii::debug('No user logged in, the problem is there', __METHOD__);
    } else {
        Yii::debug("User $user->id logged in", __METHOD__);
        if (!Yii::$app->user->can('createCountry') {
            Yii::debug('User cannot create country', __METHOD__);
            if (!Yii::$app->user->can('admin') {
                Yii::debug('User does not have admin role', __METHOD__);
            } else {
                Yii::debug('Admin role does not have createCountry child', __METHOD__);
            }
        } else {
            Yii::debug('User can create country, ALL DONE!', __METHOD__);
        }
    }
    // Remove above this line after finding the problem

    // You would keep the logic below this line after finding the problem
    if(!Yii::$app->user->can('createCountry')) {
        throw new ForbiddenHttpException('You are not allowed to do that'); 
    }
    // No 'else' after throwing, more readable code
    // Your logic goes here, the user can create countries
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think:

1. Your code is almost ok
2. Missing **addChild($adminRole, $createCountry)**;
3. The permission is checked against the table **auth_item_child**.

   ```
    Parent          Child
    admin           'createCountry'
    admin           'deleteCountry'
    guest           'indexCountry'
    ....
   ```
4. Then you can

   ```
    if(Yii::$app->user->can('createCountry')){
   ```